# Start Bootstrap SB Admin Scrolling Nav Bar Items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, themes

For those people who are having issue with the navbar not scrolling (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/). There might be a better way to do this, but I fixed it by adding the following to the css file.

```
.navbar-sidenav {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    -ms-overflow-style: none !important;
}
.navbar-sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px !important;
    display: none !important;
}
```

Good luck,
Greg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [what makes good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [how to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while to figure this out.  The above code allows for scrolling but the overflow messed up the tooltip.  Had to modify a few other things to make it work.  Add the extra css code below, change the javascript function below and add the class to the html file like the code below.  Hope this helps some others...

CSS

```
.sidenav-not-toggled {
    overflow-x: auto !important;
}
.navbar-sidenav {
    -ms-overflow-style: none !important;
}
.navbar-sidenav::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px !important;
    display: none !important;
}
```

JavaScript

```
// Toggle the side navigation
$("#sidenavToggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").toggleClass("sidenav-toggled");
    $(".navbar-sidenav").toggleClass("sidenav-not-toggled");
    $(".navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapse").addClass("collapsed");
    $(".navbar-sidenav .nav-link-collapseLink").addClass("collapsed");
    $(".navbar-sidenav .sidenav-second-level, .navbar-sidenav .sidenav-third-level").removeClass("show");
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav sidenav-not-toggled" id="dashboardAccordion">
```